# Keeping Text in Edit Text Present unless Modified

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried searching on stackoverflow and android develoer websites, but I could not find any method/command as to how to keep the text entered by the user in the Edit Text box even when we close the activity.

What I am trying to make is that I have a an activity which takes input from user in the editText box, and when the user press the back button to go to a different acitviy and then when (s)he comes (s)he finds the text as last entered instead of the blank editText dialog box.

Apology if the question has been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use sharedPreferences to do this : 
Save your preference like this (when activity was paused for example) :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
prefs.edit().putString("myvalue", myEditText.getText().toString()).apply();
```

And restaure the value on the onCreate method of your activity :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
myEditText.setText(prefs.getString("myvalue", ""));
```

You activity look like this at the end :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, ShakeService.class));

        EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        myEditText.setText(prefs.getString("myvalue", ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.edit().putString("myvalue", myEditText.getText().toString()).apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: `myEditText.getText()` needs to be `myEditText.getText().toString()`

Comment: @jaumard I have 2 activities and I am using shared preferences in both.So what is happening now is if I change the editText value of Activty1 , the value of same editText is also changed for Activity.What could be the problem?I am using the same preferences name.

Comment: Preferences are the same for all your applications so if you don't want the same value for each activity just change de preference name (one for each activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it in persistent storage. Using a SharedPreferences may be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do like this then you need to store all edittext value in **preferences** when  **onbackpress()** called.

When we come again in activity then set text of edittext from preferences in **onCreate()** or **onResume().**